# How to implement a function to modify the home page of a job in a Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins

I have a question about how can I implement a function to modify the home page of a Jenkins job. 
I wrote a Jenkins plugin that generates some graphs and I want to post them on the home page of a Job, not a link to page where graphs are posted.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ChuckNorris](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ChuckNorris+Plugin) plugin is an example of how to modify a home page and build page. This is a plugin so would be a good place to start